# Get all the list of file from last 5 seconds

Tags: text-processing, awk, logs

Hi will get list of lines from the command prompt like the following.

After doing `logread` and applying some filters

```
Sat Sep 9 07:28:18 2017 notifications.google.com 192.168.150.201
Sat Sep 9 07:29:18 2017 notifications.google.com 192.168.150.201
Sat Sep 9 07:31:19 2017 plus.l.google.com 192.168.150.201
Sat Sep 9 07:34:19 2017 plus.l.google.com 192.168.150.201
Sat Sep 9 07:34:53 2017 mail.google.com fe80::dc5f:57fd:640c:6661
Sat Sep 9 07:34:53 2017 mail.google.com 192.168.150.128
Sat Sep 9 07:35:53 2017 www.google.com fe80::dc5f:57fd:640c:6661
Sat Sep 9 07:37:53 2017 www.google.com 192.168.150.128
Sat Sep 9 07:37:40 2017 24-courier.push.apple.com 192.168.150.182
Sat Sep 9 07:38:40 2017 www-cdn.icloud.com.akadns.net 192.168.150.182
Sat Sep 9 07:38:40 2017 e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net 192.168.150.182
Sat Sep 9 07:38:40 2017 origin.guzzoni-apple.com.akadns.net 192.168.150.182
Sat Sep 9 07:39:46 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com fe80::dc5f:57fd:640c:6661
Sat Sep 9 07:40:46 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128
```

Now I want to get the only records for the last 5 second changed records

After running the filter command I need in the following format

I could have done with `logread|awk '$4 > "07:35:00"'`, but the problem is I need to pass the time always. I there anything like `> '5 seconds'`, so that I can get the following:

```
Sat Sep 9 07:37:53 2017 www.google.com 192.168.150.128
    Sat Sep 9 07:37:40 2017 24-courier.push.apple.com 192.168.150.182
    Sat Sep 9 07:38:40 2017 www-cdn.icloud.com.akadns.net 192.168.150.182
    Sat Sep 9 07:38:40 2017 e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net 192.168.150.182
    Sat Sep 9 07:38:40 2017 origin.guzzoni-apple.com.akadns.net 192.168.150.182
    Sat Sep 9 07:39:46 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com fe80::dc5f:57fd:640c:6661
    Sat Sep 9 07:40:46 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to use see in the "Testing" section.

```
#!/bin/bash

# select only dates - five columns from the beginning
dates_only=$(cut -d ' ' -f 1-5 "$2")

# the last date is taking - we will calculate the lower time limit from it.
last_line_time=$(tail -n 1 <(echo "$dates_only"))

# generate the unix time (the amount of seconds from 1970) for
# the each date. It will be the additional column in the next.
dates_to_unix_fmt=$(date '+%s' -f <(echo "$dates_only"))

# find the unix time for the last line time.
print_from=$(date '+%s' -d "${last_line_time} - $1")

# adding the unix time in the beginning of the each line.
# it will be removed in the end by the awk.
paste <(printf "%s\n" $dates_to_unix_fmt) "$2" |
awk -v from="$print_from" '$1 > from {sub(/.*\t/, ""); print;}'
```

#### Testing

**Input (few lines were added - for testing)**

```
Sat Sep 9 07:28:18 2017 notifications.google.com 192.168.150.201
Sat Sep 9 07:29:18 2017 notifications.google.com 192.168.150.201
Sat Sep 9 07:31:19 2017 plus.l.google.com 192.168.150.201
Sat Sep 9 07:34:19 2017 plus.l.google.com 192.168.150.201
Sat Sep 9 07:34:53 2017 mail.google.com fe80::dc5f:57fd:640c:6661
Sat Sep 9 07:34:53 2017 mail.google.com 192.168.150.128
Sat Sep 9 07:35:53 2017 www.google.com fe80::dc5f:57fd:640c:6661
Sat Sep 9 07:37:53 2017 www.google.com 192.168.150.128
Sat Sep 9 07:37:40 2017 24-courier.push.apple.com 192.168.150.182
Sat Sep 9 07:38:40 2017 www-cdn.icloud.com.akadns.net 192.168.150.182
Sat Sep 9 07:38:40 2017 e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net 192.168.150.182
Sat Sep 9 07:38:40 2017 origin.guzzoni-apple.com.akadns.net 192.168.150.182
Sat Sep 9 07:39:46 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com fe80::dc5f:57fd:640c:6661
Sat Sep 9 07:40:36 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128
Sat Sep 9 07:40:41 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128
Sat Sep 9 07:40:46 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128
```

**Output**

```
$ ./time_range.sh "10 sec" input.txt 
Sat Sep 9 07:40:41 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128
Sat Sep 9 07:40:46 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128

$ ./time_range.sh "20 second" input.txt 
Sat Sep 9 07:40:36 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128
Sat Sep 9 07:40:41 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128
Sat Sep 9 07:40:46 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128

$ ./time_range.sh "4 min" input.txt 
Sat Sep 9 07:37:53 2017 www.google.com 192.168.150.128
Sat Sep 9 07:37:40 2017 24-courier.push.apple.com 192.168.150.182
Sat Sep 9 07:38:40 2017 www-cdn.icloud.com.akadns.net 192.168.150.182
Sat Sep 9 07:38:40 2017 e6858.dsce9.akamaiedge.net 192.168.150.182
Sat Sep 9 07:38:40 2017 origin.guzzoni-apple.com.akadns.net 192.168.150.182
Sat Sep 9 07:39:46 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com fe80::dc5f:57fd:640c:6661
Sat Sep 9 07:40:36 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128
Sat Sep 9 07:40:41 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128
Sat Sep 9 07:40:46 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128

$ ./time_range.sh "2 minute" input.txt 
Sat Sep 9 07:39:46 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com fe80::dc5f:57fd:640c:6661
Sat Sep 9 07:40:36 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128
Sat Sep 9 07:40:41 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128
Sat Sep 9 07:40:46 2017 beacons.gcp.gvt2.com 192.168.150.128
```

Comment: Hey one more help. The above log files will be read by a shell command. So can I replace $1 by 5 sec all the time and $2 as : dates_only=$(cut -d ' ' -f 1-5 "logread -e ': query' | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $9, $11;}' ")

Comment: @ChannaveerHakari **1.** "So can I replace $1 by 5 sec" - sure. **2.** You need replace "$2" to this `<(logread -e ': query' | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $9, $11;}' )`. It is called the 'Process substitution' and behaves like a temporary file. Note, the "$2" variable occurs two times in the code. First in the `cut` command and second in the `paste` command. So, it will be better to store output of the  `logread -e ': query' | awk '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $9, $11;}' ` to the variable `log_output`, for example, and then, replace "$2" to this `<(echo "$log_output")`.

Comment: Oh! Cool. The tips works best for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
dat=$(date -d -5sec +%T)
logread|awk -v dat=$dat '$4 > dat'
```

Set dat to the time 5 seconds ago and then pass this to awk using it as a variable.